Prevent OUTPUT window from opening when VSCode starts with C/C++ extension
Whenever I start VSCode with the C/C++ extension on, it opens the output window at the bottom:

This is very annoying, because it doesn't pop up immediately, so if I'm typing something in the terminal, it will jump to this window and disrupt my workflow. I can obviously close the output window, but is there a way I can prevent this window from opening in the first place?

It's probably extension related. Maybe open an issue there? I have a similar problem with the Kubernetes extension: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78496622/how-to-block-a-vs-code-extension-from-opening-output-window-on-every-parse-error
