How to block a VS Code extension from opening output window on every parse error
When using Microsoft's Kubernetes extension in Visual Studio Code, the output window pops up every time there's a Helm parsing error. This is visually disruptive.
How can I prevent the output window from opening on parse errors while keeping the extension enabled?
Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to disable output window pop - neither in VS Code's general editor settings nor the Kubernetes extensions. Have I missed something?
Here's a screenshot to show what I mean by "Output window":

Update: An issue tracker search reveals there appears to be no solution at this point and others share the pain. #1137 #1100 #929 #907
There's a community PR open to fix it: https://github.com/vscode-kubernetes-tools/vscode-kubernetes-tools/pull/1208

Unless the extension provides a setting to disable it from doing that, you're out of luck.
VS Code has decided this is out of scope as a VS Code setting which would apply to all extensions. See Add an option to prevent side panel from opening #105270.
There's a chance this will be made part of "Do not disturb mode" in a future release (which you can toggle by using the command Notifications: Toggle Do Not Disturb Mode).

It's a shame they decided this but understandable to restrict options. I wish the extension devs would just offer this as a setting as proposed in a PR.
